lm-sensors doesn't see my B450 Aorus Elite fans
$ sudo dmidecode -t 2 | grep Product
    Product Name: B450 AORUS ELITE V2

I have 4 PWM fans plugged into the 3 available fan slots on the motherboard (2 of which are using a splitter BTW)
I did have the it8792 chip detected by sensors-detect which seems to be the expected one for several Gigabyte motherboards.
However fan speed are shown as 0
$ sensors it8792-isa-0a60
it8792-isa-0a60
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:           1.79 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)
in1:           1.29 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)
in2:           1.18 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)
+3.3V:         3.36 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +5.56 V)
in4:           1.27 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)
in5:           1.13 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)
in6:           2.78 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)  ALARM
3VSB:          3.33 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +5.56 V)
Vbat:          3.10 V  
fan1:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan2:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan3:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
temp1:        +30.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp2:        +36.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp3:        +35.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
intrusion0:  ALARM

The device handles seem to be located here
$ cat /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2/name
it8792

Fans seem to have the PWM disabled
$ cat /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2/pwm*_enable
0
0
0

I can write 1 or 2 on them but they are getting automatically reset to 0
What did I miss ?
Can someone help me to get the real current RPM and to control it ?

This is a good question for the maker of the hardware as to whether you can do what you are trying.

did you run pwmconfig?  You should be able to enable control of the fans even if it cannot detect the fan speeds.

Yes pwmconfig tells > "There are no working fan sensors, all readings are 0"

right, but doesn't it ask if you see the fans changing speed when doing the test?

Yes, and they don't
